# GRPC service not running inside docker

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, grpc, .net-6.0

I have a GRPC service built with .net 6 and the docker file is also created using visual studio docker generation tool.I have created a docker-compose file for the same and the docker compose file is below

```
schedular.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      #- ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:50051
      - "ConnectionStrings__NotificationConnectionString=Server=tcp:su.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=notificat;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=dev;Password=Ad;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
      - "ConnectionStrings__HangfireConnectionString=Server=tcp:sp.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=hang;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=dev;Password=A;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
      - "ConnectionStrings__ServiceBusConnectionString=Endpoint=sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=TmqGNrKZa/0+ASbNdakl8="
      #- "Kestrel__Endpoints__Url=http://*:5000"
      - Kestrel__EndpointDefaults__Protocols=Http2
      
    ports:
      - "9004:80"
      - "50051:50051"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

When I am trying to check where GRPC service is running or not using the endpoint

http://localhost:9004/ or http://localhost:50051/ it is not accessible

I have inspected the log and no error is there.The log is below

```
2023-10-10 18:08:17 info: Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerObjectsInstaller[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:17       Start installing Hangfire SQL objects...
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerObjectsInstaller[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Hangfire SQL objects installed.
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Starting Hangfire Server using job storage: 'SQL Server: tcp:subapp.database.windows.net,1433@hangfiredb'
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Using the following options for SQL Server job storage: Queue poll interval: 00:00:00.
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Using the following options for Hangfire Server:
2023-10-10 18:08:20           Worker count: 20
2023-10-10 18:08:20           Listening queues: 'default'
2023-10-10 18:08:20           Shutdown timeout: 00:00:15
2023-10-10 18:08:20           Schedule polling interval: 00:00:15
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: MassTransit[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Bus started: sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Hosting environment: Development
2023-10-10 18:08:20 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:20       Content root path: /app/
2023-10-10 18:08:21 info: Hangfire.Server.BackgroundServerProcess[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:21       Server 543008160f13:1:c94584e3 successfully announced in 522.4092 ms
2023-10-10 18:08:21 info: Hangfire.Server.BackgroundServerProcess[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:21       Server 543008160f13:1:c94584e3 is starting the registered dispatchers: ServerWatchdog, ServerJobCancellationWatcher, ExpirationManager, CountersAggregator, SqlServerHeartbeatProcess, Worker, DelayedJobScheduler, RecurringJobScheduler...
2023-10-10 18:08:21 info: Hangfire.Server.BackgroundServerProcess[0]
2023-10-10 18:08:21       Server 543008160f13:1:c94584e3 all the dispatchers started
```

I am not able to find why it is not exposed.

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: Any help on this ?